# How do I run multiple print statements "ONCE" in a python loop (for or while),

Tags: python

```
import random

questions=int(input("How many questions do you want?  : "))
print("answer follwing:-")
for i in range(questions): 
    print("What is",random.randint(-10,10),"+",random.randint(-10,10),"?")
    print("What is",random.randint(-10,10),"*",random.randint(-10,10),"?")
    print("What is",random.randint(-10,10),"-",random.randint(-10,10),"?")
    print("What is",random.randint(-10,10),"/",random.randint(-10,10),"?")
```

The problem is that if I provide range of 2 each print statement prints out 2 making 8 statements, however I want to print only 2 questions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this using [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

questions = int(input("How many questions do you want?  : ")) 
print("answer follwing:-")

for i in range(questions):  
    op = random.choice(['-','+','*','/']) # or random.choice('-+*/') thanks to @ThierryLathuille
    print("What is", random.randint(-10, 10), op, random.randint(-10, 10), "?")
```

Comment: Or just `random.choice('-+*/')`, any kind of sequence can be used by `random.choice`.

Comment: That is correct @ThierryLathuille, But it is not very readable as Zen of python says:`readability counts `.

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar I don't see how it is less readable... A string is a sequence of characters. `choice` chooses a random element from a sequence...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I have updated my answer. thanks for saying.

Comment: Thank you so much guys !

Comment: and how to see if answers of randomly generated questions are correct ?

Comment: @JohnBlayat This will be another question.